# What are the boundaries of obeying parents?

Tags: practical-islam, parents

If one's parents are sinners, how can that person obey them ? What are the boundaries of obeying parents ?

Comment: The boundaries of obedience of parents are well described in the qur'an   and being a sinner applies to all of us. You should better elaborate your question and share some research effort with us.

Answer (score 1):

The commander of the faithful (P.B.U.H) has said :
 " Goodness towards (one's) parents is the greatest obligatory act." Mizanul Hikmah, Volume 10, Page 709

Imam al-Ridha(P.B.U.H) has said:" Allah, The Mighty, The Glorious, has commanded three things with which he has associated three other things. He associated payment of zakat along with prayers such that the one who offers prayers , but desists from offering zakat, his prayers are rejected. He associated gratitude to him with gratitude towards parents such that one who is grateful to Allah, but ungrateful to his parents , will be deemed as ungrateful to Allah. He associated righteousness with bonds of kinship such that one who is righteous, but has severed relations with his kin, will be deemed as not being righteous." Biharul Anwar, Volume 74, Page 77

so it is not our headic to concern of our parents sin and mis behave with them we should pray for them to ALLAH TO FORGIVE THEIR SIN

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful of this look that you have towards your parents that they're sinners and you're somehow an angel. I'm not saying you're a bad person, but we're all sinners, don't take the road of Iblis and think "I'm better than x".

That being said, while nothing in Quran or Sunnah explicitly says to *obey* your parents, as in to do everything they ask of you. **However**,

You *always* obey you parents to the extent that you do not disobey Allah or do injustice.

Even when you have made absolutely sure that you disobey them only for the sake of Allah, disobeying them doesn't mean treating them harshly or giving them words unbefitting of a child towards their parents. You continue to treat them with respect but explain to them your reasons kindly and ask Allah to forgive them.

Answer (score 0):

What are the limits of obedience to parents?
When it comes to obedience and obedience, it is clear from the verses of the Qur'an and hadiths that this obedience has a limit and one should not be under the illusion that the child must be completely submissive to the parents. If parents call their children to inappropriate behaviors and the children disobey them, the parents may curse and deprive the child; But this curse and resentment will have no effect; Because the separation of parents is a right and they do not have the right to call their children to disobedience so that their children deserve to be deprived of their parents in case of disobedience;

For example, when parents invite their child to inappropriate behaviors (such as quitting prayer, turning to drugs, etc.), children can defy and ignore their instructions; Because obedience to parents and fulfillment of their rights is constant obedience to God's commands, and in case there is a conflict between obedience to parents and obedience to God, obedience to divine commands takes precedence; But it must be borne in mind that disobeying them in such circumstances never means abusing them; Rather, even in these circumstances, they should be favored and respected.

ReF:http://wikiporsesh.ir/%D8%AD%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%AF_%D8%A7%D8%B7%D8%A7%D8%B9%D8%AA_%D8%A7%D8%B2_%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF%DB%8C%D9%86#%D8%AD%D8%AF%D9%88%D8%AF%20%D8%A7%D8%B7%D8%A7%D8%B9%D8%AA%20%D8%A7%D8%B2%20%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF%DB%8C%D9%86

Answer (score -3):

Nice detailed answer here: https://www.islamicity.org/5823/say-not-even-fie-to-parents/

Do not obey them if they ask you to disobey Allah.